# HTML-signature renders differently

Tags: outlook, html-email, signature

I am making a new html signature for use in Outlook 2010. It looks fine in browsers and most email clients but in Outlook 2010 it renders a bit wrong. As you can see from the first screenshot from Chrome the text aligns to the right of the image, but in the second screen from Outlook it renders below the image. How do I fix this?

**Chrome:**
[Chrome http://unihouse.no/images/sig_chrome.PNG](http://unihouse.no/images/sig_chrome.PNG)

**Outlook:**
[Outlook 2010 http://unihouse.no/images/sig_outlook2010.PNG](http://unihouse.no/images/sig_outlook2010.PNG)

Ps. I paste the code directly into the Outlook Signature html file without using the inbuilt editor.

```
<div id="sig" style="min-width: 960px; min-height: 82px; line-height: 18px; margin: 6px 0; padding: 8px; border-top: 1px #15345B dotted; border-bottom: 1px #15345B dotted; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif; font-size: 11px; color: #15345B; " >
    <a href="http://unihouse.no" title="test.no"><img src="http://unihouse.no/images/arrows3.jpg" alt="Test AS" style="float: left; padding: 6px 20px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
    <div style="padding: 6px 0 0 0">
        <span style="font-size:11px"><strong style="color: #15345B; letter-spacing: 1px">Test Name</strong>, Unihouse Norge AS</span><br>
        <strong style="letter-spacing: 1px">Storkundeansvarlig Østlandet</strong><br>

        e-post: <a href="mailto:test@test.no" title="e-post Chris" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #15345B;color:#15345B">test@test.no </a> | tlf: +47 123 45 567<br>
        Besøksadresse: Tjuvholmen allé 3, 0252 Oslo<br>
        Hovedkontor: Innherredsveien 103, 7043 Trondheim<br>    
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a table instead of floating divs. Try making a table with one row and 2 cells. Place the image in the first cell and the text in the second.

This should force them to be next to each other in any application.

```
<table id="sig" style="min-width: 960px; min-height: 82px; line-height: 18px; margin: 6px 0; padding: 8px; border-top: 1px #15345B dotted; border-bottom: 1px #15345B dotted; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',helvetica,San-Serif; font-size: 11px; color: #15345B; " >
<tr>
    <td style="padding: 6px 0 0 0">
        <a href="http://unihouse.no" title="test.no"><img src="http://unihouse.no/images/arrows3.jpg" alt="Test AS" style="float: left; padding: 6px 20px 0 0; border: none;"></a>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 6px 0 0 0">
        <span style="font-size:11px"><strong style="color: #15345B; letter-spacing: 1px">Test Name</strong>, Unihouse Norge AS</span><br>
        <strong style="letter-spacing: 1px">Storkundeansvarlig Østlandet</strong><br>
        e-post: <a href="mailto:test@test.no" title="e-post Chris" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #15345B;color:#15345B">test@test.no </a> | tlf: +47 123 45 567<br>
        Besøksadresse: Tjuvholmen allé 3, 0252 Oslo<br>
        Hovedkontor: Innherredsveien 103, 7043 Trondheim<br>    
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, but that did the trick. Thx!

Ohh and btw, is there a way to avoid the cells from resizing when the width of the reader window is to narrow (I want the text to always stay on the same line)?

Answer (score 1):

for HTML email, you `HAVE` to use `<tables>` to ensure uniformity. And then place the text and the image in adjacent `<td>` in the same `<tr>`.
[A helpful website](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/)